# How do I transfer HTML script functions to an external JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently building a website that should include a list of selectable locations. On selection, there is an overlay panning from left to right. I want to be able to send the location value from the list to my script so that I can load a specific image to the overlay.

Every time I move function from the HTML doc to my .js, the functions seem to never get called. (This is my first ever web dev project).

```js
document.getElementById("mkc").onclick = overlayShow();
document.getElementById("hide").onclick = overlayHide();

function overlayShow() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").className += " show";
}

function overlayHide() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").classList.remove("show");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="list">
    <a onclick=>Birstall</a>
    <a id="mkc" onclick="overlayShow()">Milton Keynes: C wing</a>
    <a id="MKB" onclick="overlayShow()">Milton Keynes: B wing</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div id="overlay" class="overlay">
    <div class="content">
      <button id="hide" onclick="overlayHide()">hide</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The functionality works with the 2nd script included, but when I move the functions inside index.js, it does not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your script `index.js` properly loaded on the page? You can check that by inspecting the network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Yes, I'm also using openlayers to produce a map and all the functionality is working fine for that part

Comment: Did you position the script at the *same* spot in the document, or somewhere earlier in the document?

Comment: The script is placed after the "main" section.

Comment: @trincot It doesn't matter. The script just defines functions.

Comment: Either (a) something about index.js is broken (but we can't see that as you haven't provided a [mcve]) or (b) index.js isn't loading (e.g. because you got the URL wrong). Either way, there isn't enough information to tell from the question.

Comment: @Quentin Apologies for the confusion, I've updated. (b) it is loading because there is an OpenStreetMap loaded on to the web page, included in the script

Comment: What is the point of `document.getElementById("hide").onclick = overlayHide();` since you already have `onclick="overlayHide()"`?

Comment: @Quentin The plan is to remove the latter after migrating the functions to the script file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById("mkc").onclick = overlayShow();` is overwriting the existing `onclick` *attribute* with the return value from calling `overlayShow()` (which is `undefined` since that function lacks a `return` statement).

Get rid of the attribute from the HTML and assign the **function**, not the result of **calling** the function, from JS.

```
document.getElementById("mkc").onclick = overlayShow;
```

Better, switch to the modern `addEventListener`:

```
document.getElementById("mkc").addEventListener("click", overlayShow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parenthesis `()` from your overlayShow(); and overlayHide(); assignment so you're assigning the function instead of calling it.

You have this...

document.getElementById("mkc").onclick = **overlayShow()**;

document.getElementById("hide").onclick = **overlayHide()**;

Make it this...

document.getElementById("mkc").onclick = **overlayShow**;

document.getElementById("hide").onclick = **overlayHide**;

Answer (score -1):

Your javascript is not doing what you think it's doing:

```js
// You are calling overlayShow(), and assigning its result to "onclick" not assigning the function
document.getElementById("mkc").onclick = overlayShow();
// You are calling overlayHide(), and assigning its result to "onclick" not assigning the function
document.getElementById("hide").onclick = overlayHide();
```

So this doesn't work because your script is trying to **call** a function and assign its result to the `onclick` property (since your functions do not return anything, it's assigning `undefined`).

So just assign them correctly:

```js
// Notice no () on the right side of the equality
document.getElementById("mkc").onclick = overlayShow;
document.getElementById("hide").onclick = overlayHide;
```

Comment: "So this doesn't work because your script is trying to call a function which is not yet defined" — No. Function declarations are hoisted.

Comment: @Quentin you are indeed right, I'll remove that part from the answer